# Error while fitting a linear regression "ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples"

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression, data-science

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

class MarketingCosts:

    def desired_marketing_expenditure(marketing_expenditure, units_sold, desired_units_sold):
        model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
        model.fit(units_sold, marketing_expenditure)
        output = model.predict(desired_units_sold)
        return output


print(MarketingCosts.desired_marketing_expenditure(
    [300000, 200000, 400000, 300000, 100000],
    [60000, 50000, 90000, 80000, 30000],
    60000))
```

However, I obtain the following error when I run it:

```
exec(code, run_globals) 
  File "marketingcosts.py", in  
    60000)) 
  File "marketingcosts.py", in desired_marketing_expenditure 
    model.fit(units_sold, marketing_expenditure) 
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1 5]
```

Does someone know why this is happening? I also tried to make the model.fit using np.array as an argument but it throws a similar error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to decide how to interpret a 1-d array. If this is some different samples with 1 feature each, use `np.array(units_sold).reshape(-1,1)`. If this is a single sample with 5 features (which its not, seeing the `y` values) use `np.array(units_sold).reshape(1,-1)`. Use the first option on both train_X and test_X, and you are set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. You need to transpose your data:

```
Xtrain = np.array([[300000, 200000, 400000, 300000, 100000],]).T
y = np.array([[60000, 50000, 90000, 80000, 30000],]).T
Xtest = np.array([[60000],]).T

print(MarketingCosts.desired_marketing_expenditure(y, Xtrain, Xtest))
```

I'v misplaced parameters, now it's fixed. Output now is 22000, looks good.